# Встраивание groovy в java. Безопасность

Tags: java, groovy

Как безопасно встроить groovy скрипт в java? Поясню. Допустим я подгружаю какой-то скрипт динамически в java. Я понятия не имею что он делает. Как можно защитится от таких штук как `System.exit(0)`? Или от написания чего-то в файл?

В идеале было бы классно, если бы можно было эмулировать вызов скриптов в какой-то виртуальной машине. Или что-то типа такого. Запуск в отдельном потоке не спасет. Может быть можно как-то ограничить доступ скрипта к рантайму? (этот вариант мне кажется маловероятным)

Может есть статьи посвященные данной теме? Просто я ничего толком не нашел.

Comment: запускайте в отдельной JVM или даже в отдельном докер-контейнере с правильно настроенными правами.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman Стоп, не могли бы вы разъяснить, как из одного java процесса поднять вторую JVM при этом разделять с новым процессом некоторые ресурсы (мне нужно в скрипт передавать некоторые переменные). Мне кажется это оверхедом, нет? Если есть какой-то простой путь, то опишите.

Comment: зависит от ресурсов какие необходимо разделять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри [Groovy sandbox](http://groovy-sandbox.kohsuke.org). Можно даже делать intercept определённых методов и реализовать логику на проверку вызовов.

[Аналогичный вопрос и ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219870/untrusted-groovy-script-security-in-java)

**UPDATE**

Как правильно заметил @learp в комментариях, есть еще `SecureASTCustomizer` и он работает как AST трансформация, [официальная документация](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.11/html/documentation/)

> This customizer only works at the AST (abstract syntax tree) level, not at runtime!

В то время как [Groovy sandbox работает как interceptor](https://github.com/kohsuke/groovy-sandbox/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/kohsuke/groovy/sandbox/SandboxTransformer.groovy)

> Transforms Groovy code at compile-time to intercept when the script interacts with the outside world.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, это кажется то что нужно! Сейчас почитаю подробнее и если все норм, то отмечу ваш вариант как правильный.

Comment: Да, ответ помог. В итоге вряд ли буду использовать Groovy sandbox, ограничусь статической проверкой с помощью `SecureASTCustomizer`.